# Running time for python

Tags: python, timer, runtime, fft

Hi I am trying to estimate the run time for my fft code form numpy. With different input length N. The following is my code.

```
import cmath
import math
from random import uniform
from numpy.fft import fft 
import time
for i in range(3,10):
    N = 2**i
    x = [uniform(-32768,32767) for i in range(N)]
    t0 = time.clock()
    X = fft(x)
    t1 = time.clock()
    print t1-t0
```

This is the result I got, the first line with input length N=3 should be the fastest one, but no matter how many times I run, the first one is always the largest one. I guess this is a problem with timer, however I don't know the exact reason for it. Can anyone explain this to me?

Output:

```
4.8e-05
3e-05
1.7e-05
6e-05
3.1e-05
5.4e-05
9.6e-05
```

Comment: All of these operations have overhead. It is very well possible that 2**3 =8 is so rare an application for an FFT, that the implementer really didn't consider it important to be faster than 32 or 64 points. In my personal experience FFTs of less than 256 data points have been exceedingly rare (could be useful for some spectrograms).   To get more reliable data I'd run each 1000 times and then average the time. Timers of just a few microseconds could easily be affected by  portions of the code other than the FFT.

Comment: but when I change the starting point from i = 2, the slowest one then become i=2. So I am wondering if there is a better way to calculate the runtime.

Comment: roadrunner66 wrote about a better way to time it. Also, the magnitudes of your times are really tiny. Those times are around 50 microseconds. I'm not sure, but I think there might be a very big error margin to those times. So running it way more often (at least 1000 times) would be good. Also, as to why the first one is slowest (is it? Looks like the 6th and last run are longest): Maybe Python is recycling data/memory from the previous runs? But that is just a wild guess. Roadrunner's answer is really good.

Comment: I try to create the variables before I run the loop but the problem still exist. I guess is the 256 points problem

Answer (score 1):

The time interval is too small to be accurately measured by time.clock(), as there is latency jitter in the OS call.  Instead, do enough work (loop each fft a few thousand or million times) until the work to be measured takes a few seconds.  Also repeat each measurement several times and take an average, as there may be other system overheads (cache flushes, process switches, etc.) that can vary the performance.